# How to intersect and align pixels of two images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-resizing, image-registration

I have two images of different sizes and different world locations, like this

[image]

For both images I have [`imref2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) information.

I would like to perform comparational analysis, so I need to crop both images to the same size and resample one of them so that pixels of both images align.

Are there any simple/built-in methods in matlab for this?

Comment: Doesn't [`imwarp`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html) do what you need, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: How to calculate `tform` parameter for my task?

Comment: Do you have point correspondences between the two images?

Comment: What are point correspondences?

Comment: A set of points on one image that match a set of points on the other image.

Comment: All points are matching. Both images have corresponding `imref2d` object, which contains information about where they are located in world coordinates (which is depicted).

Comment: Then maybe you can use estimateGeometricTransform?

Comment: I am not sure any transform will align pixels.

Comment: I mean use it to get the tform parameter for imwarp

Comment: So, are you sure `imwarp` will align pixels?

Comment: Also, I don't see any cutting capability in `imwarp`, do you?

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. If you have two images and a set of point correspondences, you can estimate the transformation and then warp one image to the same space as the other. Is this not what you need?

Comment: By using the same transformation to map the image corners, you can find the overlap for cropping.